# Cannot initialize the AngularFireModule in vs code

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

Hi I'm still a rookie in both Angular and firebase. I have initialized a app and I want to connect it to my firebase database. but when I  inject the Firebase providers, and specify your Firebase configuration, It gives me an error. **`Value at position 1 in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a reference Value could not be determined statically**`.

[This how the error is highlighted at vs-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT8mh.png)

**This is my package.json**

```
        {
      "name": "angular-angular-firebase",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
        "test": "ng test"
      },enter code here
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
        "@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
        "angularfire": "^2.3.0",
        "firebase": "^9.6.4",
        "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
        "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
        "karma": "~6.3.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
        "typescript": "~4.5.2"
      }
    }
```

**This is the app.module.ts  (Note:-The credentials are hidden using)**

```
    mport { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import {getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore'
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
    import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
    
    export const environment = {
      production: false,
      firebase: {
        apiKey: '********************************************',
        authDomain: '********************************************',
        databaseURL:
          'https://fire-base-learn-9a4db-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app',
        projectId: 'fire-base-learn-9a4db',
        storageBucket: '*********************',
        messagingSenderId: '*********************',
        appId: '********************************************',
        measurementId: '********************************************',
      },
    };
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment),
        AppRoutingModule,
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

(Here earlier I added the the credentials object in the environment.ts but the same error appeared so i tired adding it directly inside the app.module.ts)

Need some guidance to get rid of the error and get started.